# Eliminate duplicates based upon multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am working with student data in a school system and am trying to eliminate duplicate data (always an issue).

Currently I have student number, program, priority (high number means progress) and date program started)

The concern is that programs are not end dated so I need to find the program that started most recently, highest priority, for each student.

Data example:

```
student1 LEP Prefuctional 1 02/08/2017 
student1 LEP Prefunctional 1 12/14/2017 
student1 LEP emerging 2 07/01/2019 
student1 LEP beginner 3 02/08/2020 ** 
student2 LEP Prefuctional 1 02/08/2016 
student2 LEP Prefunctional 1 12/14/2017 
student2 LEP emerging 2 02/08/2020 
student2 LEP beginner 3 02/08/2020 **
```

I want to select the rows with the stars. How do I do this?

Comment: Refer to this article: https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/remove-duplicates.html

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use Sort option for data in columns. You will find it in Data panel. You can declare a cascade set of rules adequate to Your current needs. Take look as it appears in GUI on following image : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/El7rt.png 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GB5gn.jpg

On

Comment: That indeed works for sample dataset. In real data I don't think this pattern would exist.